# Need Regular expression for the following

Tags: c#, regex

I have to write the Regex expression which accepts - and only numbers either single four digit number or two 4 digit numbers seperated by hyphen as shown below

2751, 2759-2764, 2766-2774, 2776-2777, 2890-2897
3945-3974, 3979, 3984-3999

I have used this Regex `^[0-9_,]+` but this line `Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^[0-9_,]+$")` returns false.

Regards,

Nagasree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern that you tried is not matching as there is no hyphen or space in the character class. But when you would add those, the pattern still does not take any format into account.

You could match 4 digits with optional hyphen and 4 digits part. Then repeat that preceded by a space:

```
^[0-9]{4}(?:-[0-9]{4})?(?:, [0-9]{4}(?:-[0-9]{4})?)*$
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b0-9%5d%7b4%7d%28%3f%3a-%5b0-9%5d%7b4%7d%29%3f%28%3f%3a%2c+%5b0-9%5d%7b4%7d%28%3f%3a-%5b0-9%5d%7b4%7d%29%3f%29*%5cr%3f%24&i=2751%2c+2759-2764%2c+2766-2774%2c+2776-2777%2c+2890-2897%0d%0a3945-3974%2c+3979%2c+3984-3999&o=m)

```
var s = "2751, 2759-2764, 2766-2774, 2776-2777, 2890-2897";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[0-9]{4}(?:-[0-9]{4})?(?:, [0-9]{4}(?:-[0-9]{4})?)*$"));
```

Output

```
True
```